# Magento 2 : Redirect on cart page after login

Tags: magento2, customer, redirect

I want to redirect the customer to cart page after login from anywhere ex.login from checkout page or customer account login.

Anyone know how to do this?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Create `events.xml` from **Module/etc/frontend/** folder and paste it below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="custom_customer_login" instance="Theme\VendorName\Observer\RedirectCustomerToLoginAtObserver" />
    </event>

</config>
```

And create `RedirectCustomerToLoginAtObserver.php` file from **Module/Observer** folder and paste it below code.

```
<?php

namespace Theme\VendorName\Observer;

class RedirectCustomerToLoginAtObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     */
    protected $_response;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

        /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface
         */
    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface
    ){
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManagerInterface;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $storeObj = $this->_storeManager->getStore(1);
        $BaseURL = $storeObj->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
        $url = $BaseURL . 'customer/account/login';
        $this->_response->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask if any.

Comment: bad idea because your observer will interrupt application flow using `exit` function.

Comment: It is not working for me :(

Comment: @SnehaPanchal let me check

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** Create

> Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerLogin" />
    </event>

</config>
```

**Step 2 :**

> Create Vendor/Module/Observer/CustomerLogin.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Layout $layout,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
    )
    {   
        $this->_layout = $layout;
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /*$resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl('checkout/cart');
        return $resultRedirect;*/
        $RedirectUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart');
        $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($RedirectUrl)->sendResponse();
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using magento 2.1.8.it's not working.I'm getting 302 response from customer/ajax/login when I use your code.

Comment: bad idea because your observer will interrupt application flow using `die` function.

Comment: @SnehaPanchal its working with the same version

Answer (score 0):

For customization after-login redirect you need to add after plugin on `\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost::execute` where you should check is customer logged in and create custom redirect result.

*Example*

```
public function afterExecute(LoginPost $subject, ResultInterface $result)
{
    $isCustomerLoggedIn = $this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    if ($isCustomerLoggedIn) {
        $result = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()
            ->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: This is not working on checkout page with ajax login method Also It is redirecting after customer create and we want to redirect after login to cart page from checkout page.

Comment: yes, you also need to change behavior of `Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/authentication.js` component for redirect to custom url during login via checkout page

Comment: Can I  use something else for module development? Because we need to install the module on different instances.
Thank You!

Comment: i do not propose to change core files, you can use some techniques for js component customization's via your modules, such as mixins for example http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html